# Player controller script rigidbody velocity?

Tags: unity, c#, rigid-body-dynamics

I don't understand how this works. How does this code go about manipulating the player's rigidbody velocity? Can you explain it piece by piece?

```
//Movement
public float speed;
public float jump;
float moveVelocity;

//Grounded Vars
bool grounded = true;

void Update ()
{
  //Jumping
  if ( Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) 
    || Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow) 
    || Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Z) 
    || Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W))
  {
    if(grounded)
    {
      GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, 
        jump);
    }
  }

  moveVelocity = 0;

  //Left Right Movement
  if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A))
  {
    moveVelocity = -speed;
  }
  if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D))
  {
    moveVelocity = speed;
  }

  GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(
    moveVelocity, 
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

4 member variables that persist between calls to `Update`:

```
//Movement
public float speed;
public float jump;
float moveVelocity;

//Grounded Vars
bool grounded = true;
```

In Unity, `Update()` is called on a `MonoBehaviour` once per frame:

```
void Update ()
{
```

This detects the four different jump buttons:

```
    //Jumping
    if ( Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) 
        || Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow) 
        || Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Z) 
        || Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W))
    {
```

If a jump button is pressed, this checks if the player is on the ground:

```
        if(grounded) {
```

Gets the rigid body attached to this script's `GameObject` and sets its `velocity` property using its current speed in direction `x` and whatever the speed `jump` was set to in direction `y`:

```
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, 
                jump);
        }
    }
```

Resets the a member variable and detects left and right inputs to change the speed in direction `x`:

```
    moveVelocity = 0;

    //Left Right Movement
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
        moveVelocity = -speed;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
        moveVelocity = speed;
    }

    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(
        moveVelocity, 
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
}
```

---

The most notable problem with this script is that `grounded` doesn't ever seem to be set so I'm guessing you've omitted that part.  Also, calling `GetComponent<>` is pretty expensive when done like this.  It would make more sense to save the `Rigidbody2D` as a member variable from `Start()`:

```
private Rigidbody2d body;

void Start() {
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
```

Then you can just use `body.velocity`.